# Is it safe to read and write to a serial port at the same time via different threads?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

Is it safe to read and write to a serial port at the same time via different threads (one read thread and one write thread)? Would it be necessary to add locking around reading/writing in each thread?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation of [SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx):

> Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Since Read and Write are not static, they would not be threadsafe.  It's a very bad idea, in any case, since the SerialPort class maintains internal buffers for you.

You'll need to synchronize your I/O to your serial port.

Comment: But the SerialPort is a special case, consisting of separate Read and Write channels in both soft- and hardware. Using 2 Read threads would require locking.

Comment: Yeah - it should be okay, provided your reader thread never writes, and your writer thread never reads, BUT - this is an implementation detail, and the documentation doesn't specifically say this is allowed, so theoretically, this could change in a future version of .NET.  Also, I wouldn't guarantee that this is the behavior on other platforms, such as if you use SerialPort on the CF.  I wouldn't do it, personally, since the API's documentation doesn't explicitly allow it.

Comment: The accepted answer is wrong. The MSDN is full of missing details. The fact that thread safety is not explicitely mentioned in the MSDN may simply mean that the documentation team at Microsoft forgot to mention it. You should have looked into the source code before writing your answer. Internally SerialPort uses a class SerialStream which uses the API CreateFile("\\.\COM1") to open a bidirectional COM port. The data is read with the ReadFile() and written with the WriteFile() API. So the SerialPort is definitely thread safe if one thread only writes and the other thread only reads.

Comment: Now, a decade after the original answer, that link does not have the quoted phrase. Instead there is no mention about thread safety.

Comment: @Elmue an annoying one is reopening connections. It is ok for it to fail ongoing reads, but I don't think there is some reliable behavior for reopens. Even using a single thread you can get in trouble if you resume using the SerialPort too soon.

Comment: You do not express well: "reopening"?? "ongoing reads"?? What are you talking about? The class SerialPort in C# uses the API CreateFile() to open a port. There is absolutely NO timing limit to open a port which was closed before. If you detect any timing related problem this comes from the driver of your port or from the USB device that is connected. But surely not from SerialPort.Open() which has no timing limitation at all.

Comment: @Elmue I missed this old message, but here is a nice quote about Close "The best practice for any application is to wait for some amount of time after calling the Close method before attempting to call the Open method, as the port may not be closed instantly" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.close?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0. You can put the blame of the behavior anywhere you want, but if its common enough to be mentioned, it is something to pay attention to. Another thing, not everybody is running on windows.

Answer (score 13):

Reading and writing to the serial port "at the same time" from different threads is a standard way to handle serial port communications: one thread handles reading, and one handles writing. Acceptable.

There are a number of serial-based devices that send data asynchronously to the host machine while still allowing commands to be sent to the device itself: devices such as barcode scanners, tag scanners and cameras.

**Problems?**

Problems arise when you attempt to synchronize your communication to and from the device.

For instance, you want to write a command and then immediately read back any response. Well, in that case you would suspend the reading thread and *manually* read off all the serial port data after having written the command. After the command has been processed, the reading thread can start up again.

**Summary**

In general through, I would suggest only have one extra thread that processes all the reading of port data and fires off events, such as `DataReceived` and perform all your writes from your main thread.

Comment: Mike J, that would be 1 *extra* thread. I assume you intend to write from the main thread?

Comment: Yip. Generally that's the approach I've found to be acceptable. But as I've found, the issue really lies in the synchronization of the reads and writes and boy that can be a downright pain :-)

Comment: @MikeJ how about reconnects? I feel one need some reader/writer style locking, in the sense that only the reopening of the connection needs to lock, while for all other operations they can be done normally as long as there is no reconnect going on.

Answer (score 3):

I would expect the specific case you describe, with 1 Read and 1 Write thread to be safe.

The Read and Write channels on the hardware are designed to be used full duplex, and the software should be designed to support that too.
And although i could not find  an explicit statement about this, the example on the [MSDN Page for the SerialPort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx) also writes from the main thread while it reads on another. Without locking.

Comment: You "would" expect and it "should" be designed.... This is just your theory. This answer is not helpful. You should have looked into the source code of the SerialPort class.